# Have a class behave like a string

Tags: .net, oop, class

Is it possible to have a class that behaves like a string but allows me to have some additional properties?

Specifically, I want to be able to do something like

```
Dim A As MyClass ''Or New MyClass("InitialValue")
A = "Something"
If A = "SomethingElse" Then

End If
```

From what I can see, I need to implement a type that can be assigned in such a way that it's passed the string in a constructor:

eg `A = Something` should be interpreted as `A = New MyClass("Something")`. In addition, I then need to override the comparison operator so that `If A = "SomethingElse" Then` can be handled by my code which checks the underlying String value

Since `String` is sealed/not inheritable and String seems to have some special handling in .Net I'm a little stumped as to how to approach this.

To explain why it's required, I've got an entity class (Not EF) which is serialized to generate queries against a search index. The queries are created by specifying a lambda against my entity.

I now need to modify certain properties on the entity so that instead of serializing to a simple string (for passing to the search index), they're complex objects. I don't have control over the serialization itself (currently being handled inside Newtonsoft Json.Net) so I was hoping this would be a (quicker) alternative which would allow me to use the existing lambdas, etc...

Comment: You may also want to look at creating implicit conversions between `String` and you type (and back).

Comment: @Oded The example happens to be in VB but I'm happy ewith either VB or C# answers (or TBH any other .Net lang) hence not specifying a tag. Thanks anyway

Comment: Fair enough - you may want to include that in the question in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* do this for the assignment using a [custom implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yf7b9sy7.aspx) from `System.String`, as `XNamespace` does, for example<sup>1</sup>. Whether that would *also* work for the comparison, I'm not sure.

I'm generally *very nervous* of implicit conversions, and would urge caution around this. Having a constructor or static factory method, or possibly an extension method to convert from `string` to the relevant type, would make this clearer:

```
Dim A = new MyClass("Something")
If A = "SomethingElse".ToMyClass()
```

---

<sup>1</sup> LINQ to XML contains a bunch of rule-breaking design decisions which make it easier to use. This is an example of genius being able to trump normal good practice - but most of us don't have that level of genius.

Comment: Humility from most users is welcomed. From _The_ Jon Skeet, it's bloody impressive. Thanks for the answer. I ended up using a mixture of your answer and overriding comparison operators but I agree it stinks and I'm certainly not a genius so this code is first up against the wall when the revolution comes. Thanks again